# Can not redirect https with upstream directive

Tags: nginx, networking, https, devops, nginx-reverse-proxy

With such config a I get redirecting to google.com

```
server {
    listen 80;

    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    rewrite_log on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://google.com;
    }
}
```

but if I add upstream instead of host

```
upstream some-backend {
    server google.com:443;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    rewrite_log on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://some-backend;
    }
}
```

I am getting error from google[image]

Comment: What url is showing in browser vs what you attemped?

Comment: @dmr83457 I attemped http://localhost:8080/reqwrqwwerq
In browser showed http://localhost:8080/reqwrqwwerq


Also I used curl
curl -i localhost:8080/
and this commad return google page with 404 error

Comment: I did repository with that https://github.com/ArtemMe/devops_drafts/tree/master/nginx

Answer (score 0):

It is because of fqdn. On the server is sent ip instead of fqdn. You can fix it with that config:

```
upstream google.com {
    server 10.16.1.51:443;
}

...
proxy_pass https://google.com;
proxy_ssl_server_name on;
```

or you can manually set headers in location section:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass https://some-backend;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_ssl_name google.com;
    proxy_set_header Host google.com;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).